# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\cos t)dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, catalans-constant

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\cos t)dt=-\frac{{\pi}}{4}\ln2+\frac{1}{2}K$$

I ran across this integral while investigating the Catalan constant. I am wondering how it is evaluated.
I know of this famous integral when the limits of integration are $0$ and  $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but when the limits are changed to $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$, it becomes more complicated.

I tried using $$\cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2},$$
then rewriting it as:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln\left(\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(e^{it}+e^{-it})dt-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(2)dt.$$

But, this is where I get stuck.

Maybe factor out an $e^{it}$ and get
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(e^{it}(1+e^{-2it}))dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(e^{it})dt+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(1+e^{-2it})dt$$

I thought maybe the Taylor series for ln(1+x) may come in

handy in some manner. It being $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{k}}{k}$

Giving $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}e^{-2kit}}{k}$

Just some thoughts. I doubt if I am on to anything. I used a technique similar to this when solving $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\ln(\sin(x))dx$.

But, how in the world would the Catalan constant come into the

solution?. $K=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{2}}\approx .916$

Your learned input is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. Maybe you should try to reverse the order of the sum and the integral...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont know what a Catalan number is but the real part of the integral gets you the expression you are seeking. 
You have 
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(e^{it}+e^{-it})dt= i(2n\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}{16}) + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}e^{-2kit}}{k}$$

Here $n$ just appears because of the multivalued $\ln (e^{it})$ term but you can ignore it as they are imganiary. The expression you got correctly was

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}e^{-2kit}}{k}\right)dt$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}e^{-2kit}}{k}dt\right)$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(e^{-i\frac{k\pi}{2}}-1)}{(-2ki)k}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(e^{-i\frac{k\pi}{2}})}{(-2ki)k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(-2ki)k}$$

The second summation in this expression is gonna remain imaginary forever, so leave it out. In the first term observe that the summand is going to be real only if $k=2n+1$ as n goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Substituting $k=2n+1$, and $e^{i(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}=(-1)^n i$ you get the real part of the entire thing as

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2(2n+1)^{2}}$$

$$=\frac{K}{2}$$

Comment: A small comment about terminology: The Catalan *numbers* are $\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$. Catalan's *constant* is $1/1^2-1/3^2+1/5^2-\dots$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I was on the right track, but didn't have sense enough to finish. Thanks again. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t
     =-\,{\pi\ln\pars{2} \over 4} + {K \over 2}:\ {\large ?}}$ where
$\ds{K \equiv
     \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}} \approx 0.9160}$ is the [Catalan Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
> =-\,{\pi\ln\pars{2} \over 4} + \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{2\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi\ln\pars{2} \over 4} + \half\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cot\pars{t}}\,\dd t
> +\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{2\cos\pars{t} \over \cot^{1/2}\pars{t}}\,\dd t
> \end{align}
>   Since ( [see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) ) $\ds{K = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cot\pars{t}}\,\dd t}$:
>   $$
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
> =-\,{\pi\ln\pars{2} \over 4} + {K \over 2}
> + \half
> \color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{4\cos^{2}\pars{t} \over \cot\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
> \tag{1}
> $$

The problem is reduced to show that the "$\color{#00f}{\mbox{blue integral}}$"
vanishes out:
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{4\cos^{2}\pars{t} \over \cot\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{4\sin\pars{t}\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{2\sin\pars{2t}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{2\sin\pars{t}}\,\dd t
={1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+ \half\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}t^{\mu}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+ {1 \over 4}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}t^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+ {1 \over 4}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\mu/2 + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu/2 + 1}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+ {1 \over 8}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}\
\bracks{\overbrace{\Psi\pars{\half} - \Psi\pars{1}}
^{\ds{-2\ln\pars{2}}}}\,
\overbrace{\Gamma\pars{\half}}^{\ds{\root{\pi}}} = \color{#00f}{\large 0}
\quad\mbox{since}\quad\Gamma\pars{1} = 1.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ and $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ are the [Gamma and Digamma Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), respectively.

> $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$ lead to:
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{t}}\,\dd t
> =-\,{\pi\ln\pars{2} \over 4} + {K \over 2}}
> $$