# Finding $\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx$ without series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I was trying to evaluate  $$\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx.$$

I expanded $\log(1+x) $  as
$x -\frac{x^2}{2}... $ and got the answer. I would like to know if there is any way to do it without series expanding.

Comment: You then get another integral, which isn't easy to solve.

Comment: $$
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} dx =\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$

Comment: @Rustyn Yazdanpour I also got the same answer.I solved it in terms of $\zeta (2)$. But as I want to avoid series expansion or using the fact that $\zeta (2)= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ I want a different method.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure of any other way. Hopefully somebody has some insight for you, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Step I**
Integrating by part we get that

$$\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx=-\int^1_0 \frac{\log(x)}{x+1}dx$$

**Step II**
Letting $x=e^{-u}$, we have 
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u}{e^u+1}du$$
**Step III** 
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u+1}du=\Gamma(s)\cdot\eta(s)\tag1$$
that is the product between gamma function and Dirichlet eta function

**Step IV**
Let $s=2$ in $(1)$ and we're done.

Chris.

Comment: I did go up till step 2 in my attempts. Unfortunately, I've never even heard of the Dirichlet eta function. Is there any other way(using only elementary functions)?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: you may express $1/(e^u+1)$ as a geometrical progression sum that is easy to do.

Comment: @ Chris's sister Yes, but then you again need to know the value of $\eta(2)$ from it's series, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: I'm not sure I understand what is your desired way. I also want a proof for Basel problem by only using the knowledge in the middle school. :-)

Comment: True. I'll accept it.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: and $\eta(2)$ may be computed elementarily if you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+1/2^2+1/3^2+\cdots +1/n^2=\pi^2/6$.

Comment: I know (that's how I solved it) but would you consider that elementary?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: imo, yes, I think it's an elementary way.

Comment: Well, and how do you prove $(1)$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: without pen and paper. Yet, I have this link for you (I hope it helps you) - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282982/improper-integral-of-fracxex1/283026#283026

Comment: My point is that proving $(1)$ is more or the same work (and the general solution) to this problem.

Comment: ...and one usually uses series.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: actually, as you saw in Marvis posts, these are some useful - very known - identities that help us to finish things faster. Why shouldn't we use them? We meet them in a large numbers of integrals.

Answer (score 14):

You might be interested in this: noticing that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+xy}dy=\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}$$

We can rewrite the integral as:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}\;dx=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+xy}\;dy\;dx$$

Now read page 11 of [this article](http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/MathGradTalkZeta2.pdf) (you'll have to *slightly* adapt the above of course).

Answer (score 9):

Note that $I=\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx
= 2\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx 
= 3\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x}dx $. Then
\begin{align} 
I= &\ \frac67\int^1_0 {\frac{\ln\frac{(1+x^2)(1+x)} {(1+x^3)}}{x} } dx
=\frac67\int^1_0 \frac{\ln\frac{1+x^2}{1-x+x^2}}{x}dx \\= &\ \frac67\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac\pi6}
\frac{2\cos t }{1-2x\sin t + x^2}dt\ dx
=\frac67\int_0^{\frac\pi6}\left(\frac\pi2+t\right)dt
=\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}

Comment: This must be the best solution to the Basel problem.

Answer (score 3):

How about a contour integral approach?

Let $f(z)= \dfrac{\operatorname{Log}\left(z+1\right)}{z}$ such that $\operatorname{Log}$ is the principal log. Let $C = [0,1] \cup \Gamma \cup [i,0]$ where $\Gamma$ is a quarter-circle on the first quadrant with a radius of $1$. Notice there is a removable discontinuity at $z=0$. By Cauchy's Residue Theorem, we get

$$
\eqalign{
0&=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(z\right)dz+\int_{\Gamma}f\left(z\right)dz+\int_{i}^{0}f\left(z\right)dz \cr
\int_{0}^{1}f\left(z\right)dz &= \int_{0}^{i}f\left(z\right)dz - \int_{\Gamma}f\left(z\right)dz.
}
$$

Using the [Dilogarithm definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html), we get

$$\int_{0}^{i}\frac{\log\left(z+1\right)}{z}dz = -\operatorname{Li}_2(-i) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{48}+iC,$$

where $C$ denotes [Catalan's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Parameterizing $\Gamma$, let $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ so that

$$
\eqalign{
\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(z+1\right)}{z}dz &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(e^{i\theta}+1\right)}{e^{i\theta}}de^{i\theta} \cr
&= i\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\operatorname{Log}\left(e^{i\theta}+1\right)d\theta \cr
&= i\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\operatorname{Log}\left(2e^{i\theta/2}\cdot\frac{e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}{2}\right)d\theta \cr
&= i\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\operatorname{Log}\left(2e^{i\theta/2}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)d\theta.
}
$$
From here, we can split up the logarithm and do some computational work using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28187/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi4-ln-costdt?noredirect=1) and the fact that

$$\operatorname{Log}\left(e^{i\theta/2}\right) = \ln\left|e^{i\theta/2}\right|+i\operatorname{Arg}\left(e^{i\theta/2}\right) = \ln(1)+\dfrac{i\theta}{2} = \dfrac{i\theta}{2}.$$

After some grunt work,

$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(z+1\right)}{z}dz = iC-\frac{\pi^{2}}{16}.$$

Combining these two results yields the final answer:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(x+1\right)}{x}dx = \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share this because this is interesting, it uses a definition **which is a series.**

What you are looking at is

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

Which is the most "important" polylogarithm.

What is even cooler is this is $-\eta(2)$ which is the dirchlet-eta function.

I will show you how to compute $\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) = -\eta(2)$ using the **series** definition. It isn't what you asked for but I cant resist to share this as it is really cool. Let $S$ represent the required sum.

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

The residue theorem states:

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n) = -\sum \operatorname{Res}(f,c) \cdot\pi\csc(\pi z)f(z)$$ at the poles of $f(z)$.

Because $z=0$ is a singularity twice for $z$ (because of $z^2$) and once for $\csc(\pi z)$ it is an order $k=3$ so the residue will be according to the third derivative of $f(z)$

$$-\sum \operatorname{Res}(f,z=0)\cdot\pi\csc(\pi z)f(z) = -\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

But notice because $H(n) = (-1)^n f(n)$ is even:

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n) = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n) = -\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Finally,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

It is interesting how so many functions are tied to that one integral.